# How to get properties from .yaml files?

Tags: maven, yaml, maven-plugin

I am new to maven and yaml. I wanted to include the values from the key value pairs in .yaml file. I tried searching for an answer but could find any useful resource. Where should I save the .yml file in my maven project so that I can access properties stored in it and how to add it in my java code. A simple example would work. Thanks.

Comment: A YAML file does not contain properties. It contains a node graph. You will need additional transformation to e.g. turn `{foo: {bar: baz}}` into a property `foo.bar=baz`

Comment: I want to include custom properties into my maven project and I am not able to find a suitable way to do it. Any suggestions.

Comment: You should describe in more detail why simply using `<properties>` to define you custom properties does not work for you.